# prevent button form from submission Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

This form keeps on submitting even if it executes the return value, what is the problem with my code?

```
function formhash (form, password)
{
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("cpassword").value;
    var ok = true;
    if (password != cpassword) {
        //alert("Passwords Do not match");
        document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        document.getElementById("cpassword").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        ok = false;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $.post('insert_home.php'
            {PRIMAID:PRIMAID,EDITCAP:EDITCAP,EDITIMG:EDITIMG,EB_TITLE:EB_TITLE}).done(function(data){
            alert ("Book Successfully Updated");
            location.reload();
        });


        var p = document.createElement("input");    
        form.appendChild(p);
        p.name="p";
        p.type="hidden";
        p.value=hex_sha512(password.value);
        password.value="";
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `form.submit();`, remove it and it won't submit.

Comment: then i wont be able to post all my post variables

Comment: how can i submit the values without using form.submit()?

Comment: You mean using AJAX? jQuery.ajax()

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong variable names "password" and cpassword". You created `pass1` and `pass2` so you need to use those.

Change to this:

```
//You were using the WRONG variable names
if (pass1 != pass2) {
    //alert("Passwords Do not match");
    document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    document.getElementById("cpassword").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    ok = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it still submits the form

Comment: @user3196424 Then it's either not reaching the return call, or it's being called twice. Do this: add the line `console.log( "before return" );` into your code right before the `return false;` line. Open the developer console in your browser (this will show the console logging) and run the code. Tell me what it prints out (if anything) Do NOT use an alert popup. That can change a lot of things. Always use console.log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where formhash() is used.

The code calls the submit, not the function.

Comment: the data that needs to be posted will be hashed before it will be submitted, the formhas function will be called by another function sha512 encryption function

Answer (score 0):

If it submits the form, it' because it's falling in the else condition.

Add lots of "console.log("debug_X")" where "X" is a number different each time.

You have to add inside a console.log the value of pass1 and pass2.

Maybe you are passign a value instead of an object or maybe the reversed situation can happen also.

My instinct tells me to check both password object, and their values.
Also it tells me that you didn't check the content of pass1 and pass2 before posting a comment to Don Rhummy.

Check carefully and please search more before posting your next answer.

You can have the value by doing "console.log(pass1);" and by opening firebug and by checking the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Action attribute from Form.